# How to participate in clan war instead of being a spectator

Tags: clash-of-clans

I joined a new clan and now that the clan war has started I tried to attack but it says "Spectator can't attack". How do I get out of being a spectator (I haven't used either of my 2 attacks in the war). I went to the clan castle and the clan option and I selected "Yes I'll participate in this war" but nothing happens.

Comment: There are a couple of factors to consider. 1. If you just left a previous clan during a war and was participating in said clan's war, you will have a cooldown during which you won't be able to participate in another war until the previous war is over. 2. If you joined the clan after said clan started a war search, you won't be able to participate in that war. 3. If your clan has a number of players not in a multiple of 5 and you are one of the few that don't fit in the number of players that can war (VGO's answer), you won't be able to participate--players are picked by the one who started war

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably started the clan in the middle of a battle, meaning you have to wait this one out. 
However it may be that your leader decided he didnt want you in the war, which he can choose at will.

Comment: That didn't happen, but maybe I left my old clan just as war was declared.

Comment: If that is the case, you should be in the next one.

Answer (score 3):

The participants in a war are by multiples of 5. If a clan has 19 people whith greenlight for war, only 15 people will actually participate and the 4 others will just watch.
I am not aware though on which criteria each participants are selected.